# Update array value for multiple documents in mongo db

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
"ParentType" : {
        "Food" : null,
        "Inventory" : [ 
            {    
                "InvId":"5ea11c6569fdbb3728133c4c"            
                "Unit" : "",
                "Price" :5.0
            },
      
            {
               "InvId":"5ea11c6569fdbb3728133c4d"                
                "Unit" : "Liter",
                "Price" :10.0
            },           
    
            { 
                "InvId":"5ea11c6569fdbb3728133c4e"                  
                "Unit" : "",
                "Price" :12.0
            }
        ]
    }
```

I need to update Unit "" to Number for all elements in array that matches the criteria.
I tried writing a query as below but it doesn't seem to work right. Pls let me know the correct mongo db script

```
db.Inv.update(
  { ParentType.Inventory.$[element].Unit: ""},
  { $set: {"ParentType.Inventory.$[element].Unit": "Number"} },
  { arrayFilters: [{"element.Unit": ""}] }
);
```

Comment: Your BSON Document doesn't seem valid as there is duplicate `Inventory` key.

Comment: with a little tweak seems to be  work as expected: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y0YlKTUTvug